# Odd behavior of function return

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've spent many hours searching through all the "my function returns none" and "nested dict search" messages and none apply specifically nor do any resolve my issue.

I made a function to search a nested dictionary and return the path. This works great! I can print the results from within the function but the return immediately below the print returns None. Maybe I've been looking at it too long and it probably is right in front of my face but I'm just not seeing what's wrong here. Here's my complete code:

```
def search(v, searchterm, vid, path=(),):
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        for k, v2 in v.items():
            p2 = path + ('{}'.format(k),)
            search(v2, searchterm, vid, p2)
    else:
      if searchterm in v:
         a = {}
         a[0] = path
         a[1] = v[vid]
         print(a)
         return(a)


def main():

    mydata = {}
    mydata[1] = {}
    mydata[1][1] = 'data-1-1','reason-1-1','notes-1-1'
    mydata[1][2] = 'data-1-2','reason-1-2','notes-1-2'
    mydata[1][3] = 'data-1-3','reason-1-3','notes-1-3'
    mydata[1][4] = 'data-1-4','reason-1-4','notes-1-4'
    mydata[1][5] = 'data-1-5','reason-1-5','notes-1-5'
    mydata[1][6] = 'data-1-6','reason-1-6','notes-1-6'
    mydata[1][7] = 'data-1-7','reason-1-7','notes-1-7'
    mydata[1][8] = 'data-1-8','reason-1-8','notes-1-8'
    mydata[1][9] = 'data-1-9','reason-1-9','notes-1-9'
    mydata[1][10] = 'data-1-10','reason-1-10','notes-1-10'
    mydata[2] = {}
    mydata[2][1] = 'data-2-1','reason-2-1','notes-2-1'
    mydata[2][2] = 'data-2-2','reason-2-2','notes-2-2'
    mydata[2][3] = 'data-2-3','reason-2-3','notes-2-3'
    mydata[2][4] = 'data-2-4','reason-2-4','notes-2-4'
    mydata[2][5] = 'data-2-5','reason-2-5','notes-2-5'
    mydata[2][6] = 'data-2-6','reason-2-6','notes-2-6'
    mydata[2][7] = 'data-2-7','reason-2-7','notes-2-7'
    mydata[2][8] = 'data-2-8','reason-2-8','notes-2-8'
    mydata[2][9] = 'data-2-9','reason-2-9','notes-2-9'
    mydata[2][10] = 'data-2-10','reason-2-10','notes-2-10'

    b = search(mydata,'reason-2-4', 2)
    print(b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

The results:

```
{0: ('2', '4'), 1: 'notes-2-4'}
None
```

You can see the print works great from within the function but the return and print from main returns None. I've been programming in Python for a few years now with many functions, classes and methods with returns written but this one has me stuck.

Comment: You are using recursion, first line of output comes from a print statement in a recursive call to `search()` function, second line comes from the return statement in another call to the same function

Comment: (Meta advice: it is best not to second-guess how your question will be received, since initial negativity about down/close votes in a question can paradoxically encourage such responses. I'd say you were particularly lucky here, in that you got an upvote instead! Furthermore, question authors are not always the best judge of whether their post is a duplicate, so it is best to allow the community to vote as they will. If you do post a question that is closed, you _can_ get it reopened, by following the advice offered in the close reason or comments).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're making a *recursive* call and the `print` statement is issued in the nested call. However, the return value of `search` is not used, that's why it never reaches the `main` function.

Below, I have added a `nested` variable that is checked, and if anything was found that is actually returned.

```
def search(v, searchterm, vid, path=(),):
  if isinstance(v, dict):
    for k, v2 in v.items():
      p2 = path + ('{}'.format(k),)
      nested = search(v2, searchterm, vid, p2)
      if nested:
        # before, nothing was ever returned here
        return nested  
    else:
      if searchterm in v:
         a = {}
         a[0] = path
         a[1] = v[vid]
         print(a)
         return(a)
```

Not related, but in here you could make great use of the powerful dict literals of python

```
  mydata = {
    1: {
      1: ('data-1-1', 'reason-1-1', 'notes-1-1'),
      2: ('data-1-2', 'reason-1-2', 'notes-1-2')
    2: {
      1: ('data-2-1', 'reason-2-1', 'notes-2-1'),
      2: ('data-2-2', 'reason-2-2', 'notes-2-2')
    }
```

Also, if all your dictionary keys are int, you might as well use a `list`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, explanation and extra tips! I understand why now.

Answer (score 2):

Out of the 3 paths in search(), only 1 returns something:

```
def search(v, searchterm, vid, path=(),):
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        # Path 1
        for k, v2 in v.items():
            p2 = path + ('{}'.format(k),)
            search(v2, searchterm, vid, p2)
        # Nothing returned here
    else:
      if searchterm in v:
         # Path 2
         a = {}
         a[0] = path
         a[1] = v[vid]
         print(a)
         return(a)
      else:
         # Path 3
         # Nothing returned here
```

Path 1 calls Path 2 which explains why there is something printed but not returned to main().